# Vertically align Image within TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to have my image and textEditor text to both be centered vertically within the TextEditor (similar to the textField below it. I tried GeometryReader to no avail, along with any alignment trick I could think of.

Any help would be great!

```
HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonTwo"))
                   
                TextEditor(text: $userBio)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
            }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any problem? It's just that `TextEditor` is scrollable, so there is gotta be some scroll position that causes the image to appear "misaligned". Try adding a `border` to the text editor, you should see that the image's centre Y is the same as the text editor's centre Y.

Comment: That is to say, things are *never designed* to be aligned with the text in a text editor. Why have a text editor in a place that *looks* like I'm allowed to only enter one line? How about making the text editor a lot taller, and perhaps `HStack(alignment: .top)`?

Comment: *along with any alignment trick...* did you try also [Alignment Guide](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/alignment-and-alignment-guides)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will give you some ideas

```
HStack(spacing: 20) {
    Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle")
        .foregroundColor(.mint)
               
    TextEditor(text: $text)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .frame(minHeight: 44)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
.padding()
.border(Color.gray, width: 1)
```

this is what you get when having multiple lines in your text editor
[image]

Comment: This seemed to do the trick (just adjusted the minHeight to 20. Thank you!